# ColorPicker to change one of multiple backgrounds?

Tags: android, colors, listener

I have a set of 10 ImageViews src to shapedrawables, that each separately open a colorpicker using an OnClickListener. I would like for each drawables background color to change when chosen with its respectable ImageView.

Ex: ImageView7 opens colorpickerdialog, user chooses blue, ShapeDrawable7 background changes to blue. while all other ImageViews remain grey.

I am unsure of how to go about this as im pretty new to developing. Can someone please help me understand how to reach my goal either by detailed explanation or simple example? If you need anymore information from me, feel free to ask, thank you

Answer (score 0):

this is useful

```
<TextView
  android:text="red"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:background="#aa0000"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Comment: im not exactly sure how a text view will be helpful in solving my problem...?

Answer (score 0):

you could create another activity, with theme as dialog. Pass the image reference to this activity. And display the image in the new activity.
Since it is a dialog theme, it will take the previous activity as background and will grey out the rest.
Override keydown press to finish this activity for returning to main activity.